# заменить несколько строк во многих файлах

Tags: sed

есть куча конфигурационных файлов, в которых, соответственно, есть повторяющийся кусок скрипта, который, в свою очередь, нужно заменить на другой кусок скрипта (точнее строчку). Если бы там было простое выражение, на одну строку хотя бы, то проблема решаема примерно так:

```
grep -rl --null '<regex>now' */config.xml | xargs -0 sed -e 's/<regex>now/<regex>^$/'
```

Но нужно заменить не `<regex>now`, а что-нибудь типа:

```
<command>if [ ! -z &quot;${Bla_Bla_bla}&quot; ] &amp;&amp; [ &apos;now&apos; != &quot;${Bla_Bla_bla}&quot; ]; then
    echo &quot;${Bla_Bla_bla}&quot; &gt; Bla/Bla_VERSION
else
    echo &quot;${RRRRRRR}&quot; &gt; Bla/Bla_VERSION
fi
```

все вышеприведенное заменить на

```
echo &quot;${RRRRRRR}&quot; &gt; Bla/Bla_VERSION
```

Вот с этим уже проблемы.

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться sublime text?
Ctrl+Shift+F позволяет изменять как многострочный текст, так и регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 1):

покажу общий принцип (для реализации программы *sed* из операционной системы *gnu*).

допустим, у нас есть `файл` с таким содержимым:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

заменить строку, содержащую `2`, можно так:

```
$ sed `/2/s/.*/замена/` файл
1
замена
3
4
5
```

заменить две строки, первая из которых содержит `2`, а следующая `3`, можно так:

```
$ sed '/2/{N;/3/s/.*/замена/}' файл 
1
замена
4
5
```

заменить три подряд идующие строки, содержащие `2`, затем `3`, затем `4`:

```
$ sed '/2/{N;/3/{N;/4/s/.*/замена/}}' файл 
1
замена
5
```

---

надеюсь, общий принцип понятен.

если нужно не выдавать результат в *stdout*, а менять непосредственно файл(ы), достаточно добавить опцию `-i`:

```
$ sed -i 'выражение' файл1 файл2 …
```

Comment: спс за ответ, но что-то у меня не получалось на своем примере, попробовал воспроизвести: sed '/2/{N;/3/s/.*/zamena/}' test | less
sed: 1: "/2/{N;/3/s/.*/zamena/}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: подозреваю, что вместо `zamena` вы использовали строку, содержащую символ(ы) `/`. его (их) в таком случае надо было «забэкслэшить», добавив перед каждым «слэшем» `/` символ «бэкслшэш»`\\`.

Comment: Пытаюсь просто воспроизвести используя тестовый файл, сменил разделитель на двоеточие, ошибка пропала, но и замены не произошло -->login as: user
mac-user-3:~ user$ sed '/2/{N;/3/s/.*/zamena/}' test | less
sed: 1: "/2/{N;/3/s/.*/zamena/}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'
mac-user-3:~ user$ sed ':2:{N;:3:s:.*:zamena:}' test | less
mac-user-3:~ user$ cat test
1
2
3
4
5mac-user-3:~ user$

Comment: а, у вас apple/macos. там наверняка по умолчанию стоит какая-нибудь урезанная реализация программы *sed*. попробуйте воспользоваться реализацией из [операционной системы *gnu*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: `/текст/` — это адрес, и слэши входят в синтаксис. это у команды `s` можно указать (почти) любой символ в качестве разделителя аргументов, а слэш в этом качестве используют просто по традиции.

Comment: проверил на линуксе - все работает. На маке - нет.

Comment: конечно, в операционной системе *gnu/linux* программа *sed* будет «родной» реализации. а в *apple/macos* надо эту версию установить. я даже ссылку вам нашёл — двумя комментариями выше.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку!